# Export gridview to pdf asp.net c# web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview

I have some problems to export gridview to pdf.

First , it shows error message

> Control 'ContentPlaceHolder1_GVAttendance' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

and then I tried to googling and find these codes,

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }
```

but it show error message again

> Error  5   'My.Project.Control' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Replacing the above code like this

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(System.Web.UI.Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }
```

Hope this works.